# ActiveX can not connect to Oracle after upgrading IE8 to IE11

Tags: database, oracle, internet-explorer, activex, ado

Here is the problem I have met: An ActiveX control in the system of my company needs to connect Database, Oracle 10g in fact, via ADO. It works fine in IE8 of our customers' computers, but after IE8 is upgraded to IE11, it can't  connect to database any more. I see no change on the face： connection string is same, codes don't change， Oracle is still the old one. Could any suggest what could possibly cause this problem?

ps: We use ADO2 developed by  Carlos Antollini cantollini@hotmail.com.

Thanks for commenting. There is no warning, and I can't even extract error or exception from the program. It runs on win7. The ActiveX is a small control developed by my company years agao.  The core code used to connect database is as follow:

```
        strConnection = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle";
        strConnection += ";User ID=" + m_sUserName;
        strConnection += ";Password=" + m_sPassword;
        strConnection += ";Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)";
        strConnection += "(HOST="+m_sSQLServerName+")(PORT=1521))";
        strConnection += "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME = " + m_sSQLDBName + ")))";
        strConnection += ";Persist Security Info=False";
```

the `strConnection` will be used as parameter feeds to the `Open()` method of `_ConnectionPtr` object of `ADO`, the connecting code is like this:

```
m_pConnection->Open(strConnection , userId, password, NULL);
```

where `m_pConnection` a  varible of type `_ConnectionPtr`, a pointer of `Connection`.

I am pretty sure the userID and password are right.
I guess the connection error might be related to `Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle`, like dll missing or registration problem? But I can't be sure, I don't know the underlying mechanism of ADO.

2020.6.22 Add:
I have found the same problem in win10, it seems that is not a problem of IE, msado15 which is unable to connect to database after some update. The database-connection part of the code is:

```
_ConnectionPtr m_pConnection;
try
{
    hr = m_pConnection->Open(_bstr_t(m_strConnection), _bstr_t(lpstrUserID), _bstr_t(lpstrPassword), NULL);
    return hr == S_OK;
}
catch(_com_error &e)
{

    dump_com_error(e);              
    return FALSE;
}
```

It works fine in win7 but throws exception in win10, the exception object gives information as follow:

```
_com_error &e:
m_hresult = E_FAIL
[0] = 0x536a8590 _com_error::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)
m_perrinfo = 0x013aaaa0
    IUNKOWN
  __vfptr = 0x532d120c
        [0] = 0x533001e0
        [1] = 0x533003c0
        [2] = 0x532fedc0
m_pszMsg = 0x00000000 <Bad Ptr>
```

And the description in the exception object is:

```
   CADODataBase Error
    Code = 80004005
    Code meaning = undefined error
    Source = OraOLEDB
    Description = ORA-12154: TNS: unable to resolve given connection identifier
```

Comment: Did you see any error or warning on the UI or in the browser console? Which OS you are using? Can you inform us which ActiveX control causing this issue? I suggest you try to check its documentation for IE browser version support. I try to search for ADO2 but did not get much information on it. If you are available with any link then please try to share here. Please try to provide more detailed information. With the above description, it is hard to make a guess about the issue.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I have added some details in the description. See if you would have some ideas with them.

Comment: Is this the same machine where you were using the IE 8 browser? If it a different machine then the issue can be related with some configuration and other settings.

Comment: Yes, it's the same computer. The connection was good with IE8 before, but after upgrading to IE11, it doesn't work.

Comment: It can be possible that when you install the IE 11 browser the settings get reset to default. I suggest Go to Internet options-> Security tab-> Click on Custom level button. Check and verify that the 'Run ActiveX controls and plugins' option is Enabled. See here: https://imgur.com/a/tdgNGnn Check whether it helps to fix this issue. You can also try to tweak other ActiveX related settings to see whether it helps anything.

Comment: That's set. I am not in the office of the client, so I can't give all details. But it seems all settings are normal.

Comment: Can you share the download link of that ActiveX? We can try to install on Ie 11 and try to check whether it works or not. It may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: It is not easy, it is a small plugin which needs to be embedded into a big system of my company, which I don't have in my PC . And the strange thing is that it works fine on the computer of my company's computers but not on the costumers'.. I will try to get more information about my client's computer next time I go there, and see if you could give helpful advice

Comment: We will try to provide further suggestions after checking the other information. Thanks for your understanding. If possible then you can also try to contact the developer of that ActiveX control. He may also give some hints that may help to fix this issue.

Comment: I have re-met the connection error in my win10 laptop and I have given more descriptions. Please help to see if there is a way to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Integrated security with your Oracle? If yes, then check that you have mapped the Windows account with it properly. Also, check and verify that you are using the correct user id in your connection string. I found this information based on the error message. It may help you to narrow down the issue.

Comment: What does Integrated Security mean? Could you give more details about that or some link about it? The id and password are correct, because the same program can connect in win7, but not in win10.

Comment: With that, you can log in to the database using OS credentials. It is added as a parameter in the connection string. but I am not sure whether the issue is related with it. For testing purposes, try to create a C# code and try to login to the database using the above connection string to check whether it lets you to connect it or not. If not then maybe issue is something else and maybe it is not IE browser related issue.